# Eclipse + Gradle + Spring Boot project (build error)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I am new to spring boot + gradle project. I was working with github and worked fine. Btw, I deleted my local repository and imported the project from github again. This error occurred. In my opinion, the gradle project cannot be built. I am trying to solve this problem for the whole day, but I couldn't.

please anyone help!

What I have tried

- change proejct name on .project file.
- changed jre version

[image: Application.java]

[image]

[image: my project directory]

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: working with a team and I have to do my part, but cannot start due to this error...

Comment: Please show what you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Libraries_, your `build.gradle` and if it exists also the `module-info.java` file.

Comment: Thank you for your help! just solved by making a new project...

Answer (score 0):

First try building the project using gradle.bat build. Once the build is successful try refreshing the project i.e. `right click on the project -> gradle -> refresh project`.

Ideally this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tired that so many times. it does not work...

Comment: is your gradle build successful? Based  on the errors it looks like you were unable to download all the dependencies.

Comment: yes... that's right... build is failed... btw... I have no idea why it cannot be build. it worked before. I checked gradle and java version and everything...

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but thought it might be helpful for someone like me who faced exactly the same situation when I imported an existing Gradle Project in my STS (Eclipse).

I had to match my local pc's JAVA_HOME env variable and this block (jdk 21 in my case) in `build.gradle`:

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}
```

Then I did `gradlew clean build` followed by `right click on the project -> gradle -> refresh project` (as suggested by @Nagaraju Chitimilla) and I was able to resolve all my errors.